# Does Mexico still exist in the Thundercats universe?

Tags: thundercats

In Thundercats episode 85th,  [Sideswipe](https://thundercats-ho.fandom.com/wiki/Sideswipe)

> As Snarfer goes to the Berbil Village to get some Mexican takeout food
> for the ThunderCats' dinner

At first I thought this was something from the Spanish dub I was listening to, but the Thundercats English wikia proves it's also in the  original English version. So how is this possible?

Does Mexico still exist in the Thundercats universe, or did Mexican cuisine survive from the ancient past or something?

Comment: Is the Thundercats series even set on Earth in the first place?

Comment: Even if it takes place on our Earth, it's possible that Mexico no longer exists as a sovereign country but is still recognized for its cultural contributions. For example, today you can read Sumerian literature even though Sumeria as a country has not existed in over three thousand years. In the Star Trek universe of the 24th century, places like France and New Zealand are still referenced as geographic and/or cultural locations even though they had long since lost or given up their independence to United Earth and the Federation.

Comment: @Nu'Daq I believe [_Thundercats_ was set on Third Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThunderCats_(1985_TV_series)#Plot), which was far less successful with critics than the first two Earths.

Comment: It could also be a translation convention to indicate a food like Mexican.

Comment: @Mary - They mention a bunch of different Mexican foods; Refried beans, chilli con carne, tacos, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually two separate questions here.

**Does Mexico exist on Third Earth?**

No (probably). We see 'Third Earth' from space on several occasions and there are no obviously corresponding landmasses with present-day ones. The continents are *dramatically* different.

[image]

**What is Snarfer going to get?**

Snarfer is heading to get takeout food. Tacos, refried beans, chilli con carne are all mentioned as being available at

> "Ro-Bear Roberto's Taco Stand in the Berbil Village".

The [Ro-Bear Berbils](https://thundercats.fandom.com/wiki/Ro-Bear_Berbils) are a race of mechanical bears that landed on Third Earth after leaving their home planet of Ro-Bear. It would seem likely that they carry with them the knowledge of how to cook Mexican-***style*** foods (along with the various seeds and processes required to make the ingredients). There's no special need for 'Mexican food' to come from literal Mexico.

Comment: Those maniac Ro-Bear Berbils! They blew it up! THEY BLEW IT ALL TO HELL!!!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Yeah, but they rescued the important stuff, tacos and ground beef